# how to know that android studio is 64 or 32 bit?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio.I installed it few months ago and i cannot remember if it's 64 or 32 version. Can anyone please suggest that how one can find that the android studio is 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: If you download from android official site it should be same as your windows bits.(32 or 64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Menu `Android Studio` / `About Android Studio` and you will see something like this:

```
Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017  

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

`x86` = 32 bit version
`x86_64` = 64 bit version

Answer (score 1):

Goto Help -> About ->enter

```
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 2, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Here, the JVM is using OpenJDK **64-bit**.

Comment: What do these mean? How do I tell if it's 32bit or 64bit from this? Just the "amd64" for the JRE?

Comment: By this  u can tell its 64-bit   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit